# If Hashset 'add' complexity is O(1), then how unique elements are stored?

Tags: data-structures, big-o, hashset

Big-O - In order to add an element to a HashSet the complexity is O(1), then how does a HashSet determine if the element to be added is unique or not ?

Comment: Are you asking about hash table data structure in general or about particular implementation? And there is no magic, insert operation in a hash table is not `O(1)` in the worst case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the choice of hash table, but in most traditional implementations of hash tables (linear probing, chained hashing, quadratic probing, etc.) the cost of doing an insertion is *on expectation* O(1) rather than *worst-case* O(1). The O(1) term here comes from the fact that *on average* only a constant number of elements in the hash table need to be looked at in the course of inserting a new value. In linear probing, this happens because the expected length of the run of elements to check is O(1), and in chained hashing it's because there are only on expectation O(1) elements in the bucket in question. The hash table then can check whether the newly-inserted element is equal to any of these values when performing an insertion. If so, we know it's a duplicate. If not, then we know the new element can't be a duplicate; we've checked every element that could possibly be equal to it. That means that *on average* the cost of an insertion is O(1) *and* we can check for uniqueness at the time of insertion.